# Sub string functionality in Angular

Tags: angular

I want set true/false condition based on the url. Let's say my url had `/test/demo`  I want set my condition to `true` if not I want to set it to `false`. any solution ?

Comment: `const x = the_uri === '/test/demo';`

Comment: Yor are using angular you may pass data for each route and better to check the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
let x = window.location.href.indexOf("/test/demo") !== -1
```

(Edits made after comments)